# How to get count of a name next to the column?

Tags: excel, unique, data-manipulation

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 2 |
| Andrew | 1 |
| Mike | 2 |

How can I get a count column like this in Excel? Note: I **don't** want something like this:

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | 2 |
| Andrew | 1 |

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)` then copy it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS()`. In ***Microsoft-365*** you can define criteria a range of cells and counting results will spill automatically for those criteria ranges. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A4)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't see any difference of your formula and mine other than using `LET()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The difference is that the calculation is not unneccessarily made more complicated byr running it through Let() first. Why would you take such a long road? or the ridiculous MMULT and SEQUENCE approach.

Comment: @teylyn mam sorry, while i was updating the solution using `COUNTIFS()` Scott Sir has already commented at that time, so i had to redo, using `MMULT()` and then later I have updated with `COUNTIFS()` and `LET()` Thank you for your insight, really helpful thanks again

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I like simplicity. Many user will confused when you mix few function to do a simple calculation. Microsoft recommend to use `LET()` function when you need repeated use of same range or calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,A2:A4,
     MMULT(N(α=TOROW(α)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(α),,,0)))
```

---

Or, like this

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A2:A4,
     COUNTIFS(A:A,α))
```

---

Comment: Why? Could it possibly be any more complicated? What's wrong with good old CountIF()?

Comment: Yes I have shown with `COUNTIFS()` as well.